# Algebraic independence of exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Friends,

Do you know of a neat proof of the linear independence (over $\mathbb{C}$)
of the functions $f(t) = e^{at}$ and $g(t)=e^{bt}$ when $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: This is a consequence of the Lindemann-Weierstrass-theorem, but you surely want an easier solution.

Comment: You are right...

Comment: Can't you do with $$\alpha e^{at}+\beta e^{bt}=0\iff e^{(a-b)t}=-\frac\beta\alpha=Cst$$ What am I missing ?

Comment: Rolling back the edit as the intended version was asked anew. Reclosing, because the older version is a duplicate. The edited version is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2017138/11619).

Answer (score 0):

$f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{C}$ iff $f=\alpha g$, for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

This implies $\alpha=1$ by evaluating at $t=0$.

But clearly $f=g$ iff $a=b$.

Comment: The question has been edited…